# MySQL JOIN: Multiple fields same name

Tags: mysql, join

I'm no pro in SQL but I'm playing around with the following SELECT:

```
SELECT 
        certificate.id, 
        certificate.date_created,
        certificate.date_approved,
        certificate.notes,
        certificate.id_user_student,
        certificate.id_user_exm,
        certificate.id_user_eval,

        user.name AS student_name,
        user.name AS exm_name,
        user.name AS eval_name

        FROM certificate
        LEFT JOIN 
            user ON certificate.id_user_student = user.id AND
                    certificate.id_user_exm = user.id AND
                    certificate.id_user_eval = user.id
```

My ideia with this is to be able to take the `name` column from the table `user` and `JOIN` it into the `certificate` table for all user id fields placed.

In the table `certificate` the columns `id_user_student`, `id_user_exm`, `id_user_eval` contain user Ids available on the table `user` and I want to their names on the result set.

My current query only works fine for the first result. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: INNER JOIN? Also, not sure why the ID has to match all three  id_user_student, id_user_exm, id_user_eval....consider normalizing the certificate table so that your ON condition would just be matching one primary key with one foreign key....

Comment: @A.O.  I think the OP wants a separate name lookup for each of the three foreign key columns.

Comment: @spencer7593 you're right, because all the students, emxs and evals are people on the `user` table and all them are involved in the certification process. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need three join operations, one for each "lookup" of a name based on id. You'll need three references to the user table, one for each foreign key reference, for example:

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.date_created
     , c.date_approved
     , c.notes
     , c.id_user_student
     , c.id_user_exm
     , c.id_user_eval
     , s.name AS student_name
     , e.name AS exm_name
     , v.name AS eval_name
  FROM certificate c
  LEFT
  JOIN user s ON s.id = c.id_user_student
  LEFT
  JOIN user e ON e.id = c.id_user_exm
  LEFT
  JOIN user v ON v.id = c.id_user_eval
```